# Vertical scroll of carousels on mobile screens

Tags: mobile, scroll, carousel, primevue

Is there a css property that enables vertical scrolling of a carousel on mobile screens? by default a PrimeVue carousel blocks the scrolling of the page by passing over the carousel, it is possible to scroll only horizontally